# Delete row before update if conflict

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with columns:

- microservice_id
- transport_id
- is_default
- ...

and a unique key (microservice_id, transport_id)
I've tried query

```
UPDATE microservices_transports
SET
    transport_id = :next,
    username     = :username,
    password     = :password,
    is_default   = COUNT((SELECT *
                    FROM
                      (DELETE FROM microservices_transports AS mt WHERE mt.transport_id = :NEXT AND mt.microservice_id = microservice_id RETURNING *)
                    WHERE is_default = TRUE
                   )) > 0
WHERE
transport_id = :prev
```

The main idea is to delete all conflict rows before update but DELETE subquery won't working. How can I fix it?

> [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "FROM"

near DELETE

Comment: how not working?.. error?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: *[42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "FROM"* near DELETE as I think

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky

Answer (score 0):

I would try to refactor the statement:

data:

```
t=# select * from a;
 i
---
 1
(1 row)
```

smth like your:

```
t=# begin; update a set i = (select count(*) from (delete from a returning *));
BEGIN
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "from"
LINE 1: update a set i = (select count(*) from (delete from a return...
```

refactored:

```
t=# with d as (delete from a where i = 1 returning *)
, c as (select count(*) from d)
update a set i = c.count from c;
UPDATE 0
```